# How to increment object value based on sibling value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to style a table of contents list.

I'm working with an object like this

```
const toc = [
  { anchor: "web-dev", level: 3, text: "Web dev" },
  { anchor: "ww2", level: 3, text: "WW2" },
  { anchor: "something", level: 4, text: "something" },
  { anchor: "lists", level: 4, text: "Lists" },
  { anchor: "books", level: 4, text: "Books" },
  { anchor: "other-books", level: 4, text: "Other books" },
  { anchor: "more-books", level: 3, text: "more books" },
];
```

At the moment I created this which works fine

```
  toc.forEach(function (entry) {
    entry.level = entry.level == 1 ? 0 : entry.level;
    entry.level = entry.level == 2 ? 5 : entry.level;
    entry.level = entry.level == 3 ? 10 : entry.level;
    entry.level = entry.level == 4 ? 15 : entry.level;
    entry.level = entry.level == 5 ? 20 : entry.level;
    entry.level = entry.level == 6 ? 25 : entry.level;
    tocHTML += `<li style="margin-left: ${1 * (10 + entry.level)}px"> </li>`;
  });
```

But is there a way to say, if there's no `entry.level` 1 or 2 then level 3 should not have padding, and so on?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about what you are asking, The question you ask at the bottom seems inconsistent with the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What's the purpose of multiplying by 1?
2. You have a bug. If `level === 2`, then the margin is always `30px`. Because of 2 conditions `== 2` and `== 5` one by one.
3. You are probably looking for the following code:

```js
function anchorsToHtml(anchors) {
    const minLevel = Math.min(...anchors.map(({ level }) => level));
    return anchors
        // anchor object to HTML tag string
        .map(a => anchorToTag(a, minLevel))
        // join tags together
        .join('')
}

function anchorToTag({ anchor, level, text }, minLevel) {
    const indentation = 10 + (level - minLevel) * 5;
    return (
        `<li style="padding-left: ${indentation}px">
            <a href="/${anchor}">${text}</a>
        </li>`
    )
}

const toc = [
  { anchor: "web-dev", level: 3, text: "Web dev" },
  { anchor: "ww2", level: 3, text: "WW2" },
  { anchor: "something", level: 4, text: "something" },
  { anchor: "lists", level: 4, text: "Lists" },
  { anchor: "books", level: 4, text: "Books" },
  { anchor: "other-books", level: 4, text: "Other books" },
  { anchor: "more-books", level: 3, text: "more books" },
];

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = anchorsToHtml(toc);
```

```html
<div id="container"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the min level value first and subtract as you go.

```js
const toc = [
  { anchor: "web-dev", level: 3, text: "Web dev" },
  { anchor: "ww2", level: 3, text: "WW2" },
  { anchor: "something", level: 4, text: "something" },
  { anchor: "lists", level: 4, text: "Lists" },
  { anchor: "books", level: 4, text: "Books" },
  { anchor: "other-books", level: 4, text: "Other books" },
  { anchor: "more-books", level: 3, text: "more books" },
];

const getItems = (toc) => {
  const minLevel = toc.reduce((a, v) => (a > v.level) ? a = v.level : a, 999);
  return toc.map(t => `
  <li class="level${t.level - minLevel}">
    ${t.text} (${t.level - minLevel})
  </li>
`).join('');
} 

document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML = getItems(toc);
```

```css
.level0 {
  color: red;
}

.level1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.level2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.level3 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.level4 {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indent the specific levels chosen only and by one tab per included level (so that if they all were `1`, `3` or `6`, the `3`'s would be one indent in from the `1`s and the `6`s would indent one step further, then you might want to sort the unique levels and use the index in that list for further calculations.  Perhaps it might look like this:

```js
const tocLis = (
  toc, 
  levels = [... new Set (toc .map (({level}) => level))] .sort ((a, b) => a - b)
) => toc .map (entry => `<li style="margin-left: ${
  10 + 5 * levels .indexOf (entry .level)
}px">${entry .text}</li>`) .join ('')

const toc = [{anchor: "web-dev", level: 3, text: "Web dev"}, {anchor: "ww2", level: 3, text: "WW2"}, {anchor: "something", level: 4, text: "something"}, {anchor: "lists", level: 4, text: "Lists"}, {anchor: "books", level: 4, text: "Books"}, {anchor: "other-books", level: 4, text: "Other books"}, {anchor: "more-books", level: 3, text: "more books"}]

console .log (tocLis (toc))

// tocHTML +=  tocLis (toc)
```